# How to make hql selects in spring-batch?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hql, spring-batch

I want to use `spring-batch` for retrieving and processing data from a postgres db.

I have a working SQL statement that would give me the full result set (about 400k entries):

`private static final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM MyDataTable ";`

Now I want to use the `JpaPagingItemReader` so that the data is fetched (and written elsewhere) in chunks:

```
JpaPagingItemReader<MyEntity> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
reader.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
reader.setQueryString(QUERY);
```

But it does not work:

```
[] 2014-09-17 16:31:58,234 ERROR : QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [SELECT * FROM my_data_table]
```

I also tried `SELECT FROM MyDataTable` and `SELECT m FROM MyDataTable m` without the star. Same result.
So, how can I execute that `hql` query with spring-batch?

By the way: the query works fine in a sql editor like pgAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT m FROM MyDataTable m` is almost correct (it is valid `JPQL` query as long as you have entity calles `MyDataTable`). So, it seems that you don't have entity class named `MyDataTable`.

As `JpaPagingItemReader#setQueryString(String)` accepts `JPQL` queries you should make sure that you have *entity class* for this table and then you should use its name instead `MyDataTable`.

By the way - for `HQL` queries there's [HibernatePagingItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/HibernatePagingItemReader.html).

Comment: Yes I do have the correct entty named. The error also clearly states the `*` is unexpected...

Comment: @membersound what's the error for `SELECT m FROM MyDataTable m`?

Comment: I retried, and now it works. Strange, but I have to admint you were correct. Thanks! Still that does not explain why `DISTINCT` is not working...

Comment: @membersound update your post, there's no question about `DISTINCT` (but title) :)

Comment: OK before that get's confusing I'll open a new question on distinct.